# Hover effects stay on Bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got `navbar-fixed-top`, which changes colors after scrolling, such as a `background-color`, `color`, `border-color`.

There is little script, which doin' it:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#home');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.navbar').css('background-color', 'white');
          $('.navbar a').css('color', 'black');
          $('.navbar a').hover(function() {
            $(this).css('border-color', 'black')
          });
       }
       else {
          $('.navbar').css('background-color', 'transparent');
          $('.navbar a').css('color', 'white');
          $('.navbar a').hover(function() {
            $(this).css('border-color', 'white')
          });
          $('.navbar a').css('border-color', 'transparent');   
       }
   });
    }
});
```

But after all that, I've got stayed hover effect. It appears once, if you hold the points of navbar with the mouse, but does not disappear if you remove it.

Here it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5T7U.png

Here is [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12770/)

Border didn't disappear.

How to fix that?

Comment: A JSFiddle or complete code include the HTML n CSS would be easy to give you a solution.

Comment: @XahedKamal added JSFiddle example.

Comment: why not you use a class instead of applying the css using javascript? it would be a lot of easier if you do it using class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this codes. You'll get what you are trying to achieve without any issues-

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#home');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.navbar').addClass('onscroll');
       }
       else {
          $('.navbar').removeClass('onscroll');       }
   });
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#home .nav a {
    color:white;
}

.nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-custom {
    color: white;
    margin-top: 2em;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    float: right;
    height: 70px;
}

.nav li {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.nav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background 0.5s;
    margin-right: 35px;
}

.nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
}

.jumbotron {
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url(''); 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.span12 {
    text-align: center
}

#main {
    height: 20px;
}

.navbar.onscroll{
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar.onscroll a{
    color: #000 !important;
}

.navbar.onscroll a:hover{
    border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home" class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#touch">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#testimon">Blog</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">About</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
    
            <div id="main" class="main">
                <h1>h1</h1> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <a href="#services">services</a>
                            <p>Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                                Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                                Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                                Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                                Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            Aasdasdad<br>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats what I need.

Answer (score 0):

In your if block your adding a background color on hover but u need to remove that on blur event which is missing. Anyway I suggest you do the same using css3, which is best suited for your case.

With css3 you don't need to worry about processing on blur event unlike when using jquery.

**CSS3 CODE**

```
.active: hover {
     background-color : black;  
}
```